# Dual network connection

Tags: networking

I have a usb cellular modem and a Home LAN connection on my Ubuntu 10.10 box.

Both work independently.

I want to know how to have both connected at the same time, and be able to specify which application uses which device to connect to the internet.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Anyone know if you could set up chroot environments to force families of apps on to the same connection?

Comment: Helps when apps aren't coded to use proxies.

Comment: proxychains applaunchcommand   seems pretty straightforward and 3proxy supports both forwarding of tcp and udp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way to tell an application to use a specific connection, you can do two different but complex things in order to acheve the same result.

First you can bind the two networks together so they're both being used:

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/21544-42-combining-multiple-internet-connections-home-network

The other is that you set up one connection as a proxy service and configure individual apps to use the proxy instead of the general network.

http://www.ehow.com/how_5019947_set-up-proxy-server-ubuntu.html

Comment: i like option 2 as a solution +1